# App is not a DOM element

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm getting an error that my  Component is "not a DOM element" through my Index.js file When I run `npm start` for some reason. I'm trying to work on my school project, and this is inhibiting my from finishing. Is there something that I may have missed that I was supposed to add? My Index.js file is:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './Components/App/App.js';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

And my App.js file is:

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import SearchBar from '../SearchBar/SearchBar';
import SearchResults from '../SearchResults/SearchResults';
import Playlist from '../Playlist/Playlist';
import Spotify from '../../util/Spotify.js';


class App extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   searchResults: [],
   playlistName: 'New Playlist',
   playlistTracks: [{name: 'Not Today', artist: 'Sevendust', album: 'Kill The Flaw'}]
  }
  this.addTrack = this.addTrack.bind(this);
  this.removeTrack = this.removeTrack.bind(this);
  this.updatePlaylistName = this.updatePlaylistName.bind(this);
  this.savePlaylist = this.savePlaylist.bind(this);
  this.search = this.search.bind(this);
 }

 addTrack(track) {
  const ids = Playlist.collectIds(this.state.playlistTracks);
  let newId = true;
  for(let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
   if(ids[i] === track.id) {
    newId = false;
   }
  }
  if(newId) {
   this.setState({playlistTracks: this.state.playlistTracks.push(track)});
  }
 }

 removeTrack(track) {
  const ids = Playlist.collectIds(this.state.playlistTracks);
  let trackIndex = -1;
  for(let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
   if (ids[i] === track.id) {
    trackIndex = i;
   }
  }
  if (trackIndex !== -1) {
   const newPlaylist = this.state.playlistTracks.splice(trackIndex, 1);
   this.setState({playlistTracks: newPlaylist});
  }
 }

 updatePlaylistName(name) {
  this.setState({playlistName: name});
 }

 savePlaylist() {
  let trackURIs = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < this.state.playlistTracks.length; i++) {
   trackURIs.push(this.state.playlistTracks[i].uri);
  }
  Spotify.savePlaylist(this.state.playlistName, trackURIs);
  this.setState({playlistName: 'New Playlist', searchResults: []});
 }

 search(term) {
  Spotify.search(term);
 }

 render() {
  return (
   <div>
      <h1>Ja<span className="highlight">mmm</span>ing</h1>
      <div className="App">
        <SearchBar onSearch={this.search} />
        <div className="App-playlist">
           <SearchResults searchResults={this.state.searchResults} onAdd={this.addTrack} />
           <Playlist 
            playlistName={this.state.playlistName}
            playlistTracks={this.state.playlistTracks}
            onRemove={this.removeTrack}
            onNameChange={this.updatePlaylistName}
            onSave={this.savePlaylist}
           />
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
  );
 }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Where is your html?

Comment: @orabis All JSX is there and in render functions of the different components

Comment: I am asking to check an element with the id root, for which you have the following call document.getElementById('root')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code basically says "In my HTML code, I have an element with an id='root', render `<App>` into that"

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

So you need to have a HTML document that might look something like this:

```
<html>
<body>
  <div id="root">React code gets rendered here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know the structure of your other app, but that's what it needs.

Comment: So I would create like Index.html and just have it render Index.js?

Comment: I have another project with the exact same structure that doesn't have this same error

Comment: Even adding an id of "root" to the opening div in the render() method, I get the same error

Comment: See updated answer, adding an element to your JSX won't do it, You need a HTML file as your starting point for React to render into.